# DATEDIFF returns Negative Values -SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-expression

This is my expression.

```
=DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,Fields!scheduledstartValue.Value,Fields!actualendValue.Value )
```

It returns both positive and negative numbers. Sometimes when a user  does not enter an 'actualendValue', it returns a negative number like '-1234'.

What i'm trying to do with this equation (below) is , if a negative value is returned, display a '0'.

```
IIf([Fields!scheduledstartValue.Value]="","",IIf(Nz(DateDiff('d',[Fields!scheduledstartValue.Value],[Fields!actualendValue.Value]),0)>0,Nz(DateDiff('d',[Fields!scheduledstartValue.Value],[Fields!actualendValue.Value]),0),0))
```

Can anyone help me , with my second equation or is there a better way to do this?,I'm just about to pull my hair out.

Many Thanks.

UPDATE 1:
I have tried :

```
=IIF(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,Fields!scheduledstartValue.Value,Fields!actualendValue.Value ) = 0,"NA",DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,Fields!scheduledstartValue.Value,Fields!actualendValue.Value ))
```

When I run this expression I get not errors, and I still get positive and negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
 =IIF(Fields!actualendValue.Value is nothing, nothing, DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,Fields!scheduledstartValue.Value,Fields!actualendValue.Value ))
```